# How to Override DPI scaling performed by the system in PyQt5 app

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

so basically I am trying to override the DPI scaling performed by the system, now this can be done by just choosing the option in the properties tab but I want to implement it into the code. Now I have tried `ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)` and `QGuiApplication().setAttribute(Qt.AA_DisableHighDpiScaling)` but it does not override the DPI scaling. So could you please tell me on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what you need to do with DPI scaling.
For instance if this is to adjust the font size you can call a such function during the UI init :

```
def adjustForDPI(self):
    dpi = self.screen().logicalDotsPerInch()
    fontSize = dpi / 96 * 12  # Assuming 12 is the base font size for 96 DPI
```

if this is a matplotlib figure, you can specify directly the DPI using :

```
fig = Figure(dpi=48)
```

if you are using QPixmap to display images you could also use this :

```
app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to change the "DPI awareness" programmatically is that it can be difficult to guarantee it happens early enough during the program's startup.  That's why Microsoft suggests using the program manifest instead.

I suspect the problem is that something in the frameworks (e.g., PyQt) is doing something that's DPI awareness dependent before you change it.  For example, it might spin up a thread that will later be used to create window.  If that happens before you change the process's DPI awareness, the thread (and the windows is subsequently creates) will have the old DPI awareness.

[SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) is an older function.  Current versions of Windows map this kind of DPI awareness into a new concept called a [DPI awareness *context*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context), which has more levels than just aware/unaware.

The DPI awareness context is a per-window property.  A process has a default DPI awareness context that is used to initialize the default DPI awareness context of threads created in that process.  The thread's default DPI awareness context is used to set a window's DPI awareness context when that thread creates a window.

There are APIs to change the default awareness context of a process or thread:

- [SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext)
- [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext)

Remember that changing the process's default DPI awareness context doesn't affect threads or windows that have already been created, and changing a thread's default DPI awareness context doesn't affect windows that have already been created.

As far as I understand, the DPI awareness of a window cannot be changed once it has been created.